# What are the fertile areas of research in Analytic Number Theory?

Tags: soft-question, analytic-number-theory

My professor once told me that Analytic Number Theory was "dead," which at the time was something of a disappointment, and which I struggled to agree with. Surely any subject may appear inferrtile in periods when researchers do not study the subject? I was just wondering, is this a generally accepted view? What reasons would be behind such opinion, and what are the fertile directions of research in this field?

Comment: Zhang's recent theorem seems pretty substantial. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131185/philosophy-behind-yitang-zhangs-work-on-the-twin-primes-conjecture?rq=1

Comment: In my opinion it is the opposite. There are lot of things in Analytic Number theory which still need to be developed/proved.

Comment: While I am not a number theorist, I know one. He seems quite alive. Moreover, he is not alone. I would not accept that view.

Comment: No, this is in no sense an accurate assessment. For an introduction to the subject, see [these notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.09/index.html) by Elkies. You may also be interested in Emmanuel Kowalski's [blog](http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/). His book with Henryk Iwaniec (**Analytic number theory**, see [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/isbn=0-8218-3633-1)) should give you a decent idea of modern directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/category/analytic_number_theory) and [these](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/category/additive_number_theory) are some sample and well known open problems in Analytic Number Theory. Also look at [this](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes) to have a flavor of the most recent 'gossip' in Analytic Number Theory world.